# don't understand why ajax isn't updating my button directly

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery

The goal of my ajax is to follow and unnfollow someone . The problem is that when i click on the button follow  the resquest is send but i need to refresh the page to the new button Not following see it . How do i make sure that it work directly without  refreshing.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('.ajax_button').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/" +$(this).attr('name') + "/toggle_follow_via_ajax",
            success: function(msg){
                elm = $('#btn_' + msg);
                if (elm.val() == "Stop Following") {
                    elm.val("Follow");
                } else {
                        elm.val("Stop Following");
                        }
            }
        });
    })
});
</script>
```

**here is the html.erb that generate  the button**

```
<div class="button_container">
        <input type="button" name="<%= friend.username %>" id="btn_<%=friend.username %>" class="button ajax_button" 
        value="<% if current_user.is_friend? friend %>Stop Following<% else %>Follow<% end %>"/>
    </div>
```

Comment: What does `console.log(elm)` show?

Comment: i got in return Object[]

Comment: Well, apparently it's empty. Can you check `console.log(msg)` then?

Comment: ReferenceError: msg is not defined

Comment: It can't be 'not defined' if you place `console.log(msg)` in the `success` function. Check your scripts.

Comment: i've called  it on the firebug console not the succes method

Comment: Did you check for server side errors?

Comment: no error the request is send it work

Comment: Try complete: Sometimes there's no success or error for some reason.

Comment: check `console.log(msg)` , add it to source after `success: function(msg){` check with firebug the response from server...

Comment: complete: isn't working and don't know why but i'm getting nothing back  when i add console.log(msg) on firebug .

Comment: if you do that in firebug, it not works because msg is local variable. why you not just change the source ? Again **check response text/headers in firebug!**

Comment: That's what i did and a checked in firebug and got nothing back

Comment: You got no response ? check your php code than

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the value returned from the server to get a handle to the button, you can get a handle to it before calling the ajax method (since you are already within scope of the button object). Like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('.ajax_button').click(function() {
        var btn = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/" +$(this).attr('name') + "/toggle_follow_via_ajax",
            success: function(msg) {
                var val = btn.val() == 'Follow' ? 'Stop Following' : 'Follow';
                btn.val(val);
            }
        });
    })
});
</script>
```

I've not tested this code, but it should work